# asp.net column chart coloring of each column in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors, charts

i m using c# for first time in a asp.net website, in which i am creating charts.
i have created a column chart- 2D, and the code goes like this,

```
protected void chrtTickets_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {

                connection.Open();


                SqlCommand cmmd6 = new SqlCommand("getHowTicketsLoggedChart", connection);
                cmmd6.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

                SqlDataAdapter dad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmmd6);

                dad.Fill(ds1);

                chrtTickets.DataSource = ds1;


                chrtTickets.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "MonYYYY";

                chrtTickets.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "aa";


                chrtTickets.DataBind();
                connection.Close();


            }
        }
```

but i have the stored procedure which returns me another field "Description" along with MonYYYy and aa as they are used in xaxis and yaxis.

but according to the "description" field value say: email, phone, portal. i want to assign a different color to each column depending upon each row's description value, if its Email-> red and so on etc.

can anyone please guide me through this?

what i mean is my data will be be like this: so i will not know what will be color type value in advance, this is the table values returned to me from db by my stored procedure.

color type| y-axiz value | x-axis

---

Email Connector| 24| Dec 2011 
Phone | 32 | Dec 2011 
Email Connector |643 | Jan 2012 
Internal | 32 | Jan 2012 
Phone |455| Jan 2012 
Portal |2 | Jan 2012 
Sales Order| 2| Jan 2012

it cold be one of the 5 types ex. email, portal but many x-axis value.

datapoints will not be known. they are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this it should randomly chose a color for the next bar

```
Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Wheat, Color.Gray. Color.Black,  Color.Blue};
foreach (Series series in chrtTickets.Series)
{
    foreach (DataPoint point in series.Points)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 5);
        point.LabelBackColor = colors[ randomNumber];
    }
}
```

here is main article http://forums.asp.net/t/1652369.aspx/1

Comment: the data which will come will be dynamic, cant assign specific no. of colors, because the no. of columns will be not same all the time.

Comment: can please anyone help, i want it to be dynamic.

Comment: sorry, but what i mean is my data will be be like this:
so i will not know what will be color type value in advance, this is the table values returned to me from db by my stored procedure.

color type| y-axiz value | x-axis 
__________________________________
Email Connector| 24| Dec 2011
Phone | 32 | Dec 2011
Email Connector |643 | Jan 2012
Internal | 32 | Jan 2012
Phone |455| Jan 2012
Portal |2 | Jan 2012
Sales Order| 2| Jan 2012