# Multicolumn dropDownList - use different colors for each column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this drop down list in an Asp page:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
  {
   DropDownList1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0:}", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Pnum"]) +
   spacer + (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Project"]) + spacer +
   (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"]));
   }
```

which nicely shows something like this:

[image]

I know that strings do not have a color property.
However, I am wondering if there is a way to get the content of the dropDownList displayed in different colors? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DefaultCellStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle.aspx) as microsoft describes, or, you could see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714387/asp-net-column-chart-coloring-of-each-column-in-c-sharp) post for more help.

Comment: I do not get how your answer fits with my question which is about DropDownList!

Answer (score 0):

with a simple dropdownlist you cannot have this behavior.
You can have this with a dropdownlist custom like this

```
<div>
    <input readonly type="text" style="color:red" id="t1">
    <input readonly type="text" style="color:yellow" id="t2">
    <select id="sel" style="float:right" >
    <option id="p1,p2">p3</option>
    <option id="p4,p5">p6</option>
    <option id="p7,p8">p9</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

css

```
input{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px
 border-width:0px;
 border-color:white;
 border-style: none;
}
div{
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: black;                
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#sel").change(function(){

    var ar = $("#sel option:selected").attr("id").split(",")                ;

    $("#t1").val(ar[0]);
    $("#t2").val(ar[1]); 
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Db8bf/

there something to work