# arrange Telerik radcombox items into two coloumns

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

How can I arrange the following rad combo box items into two columns so that the expand down is not so huge as its now. Is it possible?. I would  like to keep the list items to two separate columns with checkboxes being on both the columns.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcmbFormsAndDimensions" runat="server"   CheckBoxes="true"   Text='<%# Bind("Form_Dimensions") %>'  Width="650px" CheckedItemsTexts="DisplayAllInInput">
                                            <Items>
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="single pen"  />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="shotgun" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="double-shotgun" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="camelback" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="double pen" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="hall-parlor" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="saddlebag" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="creole cottage" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="dog trot" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="central-hall" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="gable-ell" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="bungalow" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="pyramidal cottage" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Queen Anne cottage" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="central-hall, 2 pile cottage" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text=" bluffland cottage" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="central-hall I-house" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="double-pen I-house" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="hall-parlor I-house" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Creole house" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="central hall, 2 pile house" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text=" Queen Anne house" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="four square" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="minimal tradition cottage" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="split level" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="ranch" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="row house" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="warehouse" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="depot" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="skyscraper" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text=" commercial row bldg." />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text=" freestanding commercial" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text=" single-crib barn" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="transverse-crib barn" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="other" />                                        
                                              </Items>
                                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the solution Telerik put in their website. Here's [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multicolumncombo/defaultvb.aspx?show-source=true) to it.

After that, you can add additional style to the combo box in order to get the correct number of columns.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcmbFormsAndDimensions" runat="server"   CheckBoxes="true" CssClass="SetComboBoxWidth" CheckedItemsTexts="DisplayAllInInput" DropDownCssClass="multipleRowsColumns">

 .SetComboBoxWidth{
    min-width: 280px;
}
```

[image: Example]

Above you can see an example of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your situation however this is how I did it in a ASP page taking the values from a DataSet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
  {
   DropDownList1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0:}", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Pnum"])+
   spacer + (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Project"]) + spacer +
   (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"]));
   }
```

To see the result of the above code you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511522/multicolumn-dropdownlist-use-different-colors-for-each-column) question I made for something else.